# Translate SQL statement in R code using dplyr

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I need help transalting an SQL statement regarding this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hugomathien/soccer , into r code using dplyr.
The SQL statement is :

```
SELECT Match.date ,Team.team_long_name, Team.team_short_name ,Match.home_team_goal
FROM Team JOIN Match
ON Match.home_team_api_id = Team.team_api_id
WHERE Match.match_api_id = 492476;
```

The r code that i have tried is:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data/database.sqlite")
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
match<-tbl(con,"Match")
team<-tbl(con,"Team")
table_4.2<-match %>%
  filter(match_api_id=492476) %>%
  select(date,home_team_goal,home_team_api_id) %>%
  left_join(team)
```

and i get this error :

Error in `dplyr::common_by()`:
! `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The message is pretty straightforward. There is no common variable. `home_team_api_id` and `team_api_id` have different names.

Comment: other things aside: different from SQL, R uses `==` not `=` to test for equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
Team %>%
  left_join(Match, by = c(home_team_api_id = 'team_api_id')) %>%
  filter(match_api_id == 492476) %>%
  select(date, team_long_name, team_short_name, home_team_goal)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help sir, much appreciated. The only correction is that in line 3 of your code you swap home_team_api_id and team_api_id, because team_api_id is a column of team , and home_team_api_id is a column of match :
`team %>%
   left_join(match, by = c(team_api_id = 'home_team_api_id')) %>%
   filter(match_api_id == 492476) %>%
   select(date, team_long_name, team_short_name, home_team_goal)`  @onyambu